# CTRL + Home (or End) combination not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, text

I usually use the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> to move the cursor to the beginning or to the end of a line.

Suddenly these combination is not working anymore!

Can anyone help?

Comment: wait where there are not working ?
i mean are they working on text editor like **gedit** ?

Comment: @geoh they're not working in everywhere with the typing cursor blinking.

Comment: does **Ctrl** + **Left** / **Right** work for moving left/right on word ?

Comment: @geoh Yes, it's working

Comment: well weird, do you have any keyboard shortcuts set to that combination ? I think that can be the problem. Look for that

Comment: No, I didn't add any shortcuts with that combination.
I'll try to live with that, thanks for the help :) @geoh

Comment: `Ctrl+Home/End` are not supposed to move the cursor to the beginning/end of line, [rather to the beginning/end of document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Text_editing).

Answer (score -2):

Try going to your Oracle VM VirtualBox manager and then File->Preferences->Input then choose the Virtual Machine tab.  You may find that the "Host Key Combination" is set to Ctrl or Right-Ctrl.  Click the little orange/white icon to set this to None.  This fixed the problem for me.